# A column element in the dataframe is an array, how to expand it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, and each string in the array is unique.

```html
+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+
| _1|                 _2 | _3|                 _4 | _5|                 _6 |
+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+
|  2|(Str11,Str12,Str13..|  1|(Str14,Str15,Str16..|  0|(Str17,Str18,Str19..|
|  3|(Str21,Str22,Str23..|  1|(Str24,Str25,Str26..|  0|(Str27,Str28,Str29..|
|  3|(Str31,Str32,Str33..|  2|(Str34,Str35,Str36..|  1|(Str37,Str38,Str39..|
|  3|(Str41,Str42,Str43..|  2|(Str44,Str45,Str46..|  0|(Str47,Str48,Str49..|
+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+---+--------------------+
```

Now I want to expand the WrappedArray in the dataframe, make a Cartesian product of these three columns of arrays per line, you can set the string number in the 12 WrappedArray as n1 to n12 respectively.

The expected output format as

```html
+---+-------+---+-------+---+-------+
| _1|    _2 | _3|    _4 | _5|    _6 |
+---+-------+---+-------+---+-------+
|  2|  Str11|  1|  Str14|  0|  Str17|
|  2|  Str11|  1|  Str14|  0|  Str18|
|  2|  Str11|  1|  Str14|  0|  Str19|
|  2|  Str11|  1|  Str15|  0|  Str17|
|  2|  Str11|  1|  Str15|  0|  Str18|
:   :       :   :       :   :       :
:   :       :   :       :   :       :
:   :       :   :       :   :       :
+---+-------+---+-------+---+-------+
```

There are a lot of lines here, so I try to describe the format as accurately as possible. My goal is to loop through each array in each row and do a Cartesian product on them. I sincerely hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I uderstand from your question, you must have a dataframe and schema as (this is just a sample)

```
+---+---------------------+---+---------------------+---+---------------------+
|_1 |_2                   |_3 |_4                   |_5 |_6                   |
+---+---------------------+---+---------------------+---+---------------------+
|2  |[str11, str12, str13]|1  |[str14, str15, str16]|0  |[str17, str18, str19]|
+---+---------------------+---+---------------------+---+---------------------+

root
 |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- _2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- _3: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- _4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- _5: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- _6: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

If it is correct then you should go with `explode` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("_2", explode(col("_2")))
  .withColumn("_4", explode(col("_4")))
  .withColumn("_6", explode(col("_6")))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+
|_1 |_2   |_3 |_4   |_5 |_6   |
+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+
|2  |str11|1  |str14|0  |str17|
|2  |str11|1  |str14|0  |str18|
|2  |str11|1  |str14|0  |str19|
|2  |str11|1  |str15|0  |str17|
|2  |str11|1  |str15|0  |str18|
|2  |str11|1  |str15|0  |str19|
|2  |str11|1  |str16|0  |str17|
|2  |str11|1  |str16|0  |str18|
|2  |str11|1  |str16|0  |str19|
|2  |str12|1  |str14|0  |str17|
|2  |str12|1  |str14|0  |str18|
|2  |str12|1  |str14|0  |str19|
|2  |str12|1  |str15|0  |str17|
|2  |str12|1  |str15|0  |str18|
|2  |str12|1  |str15|0  |str19|
|2  |str12|1  |str16|0  |str17|
|2  |str12|1  |str16|0  |str18|
|2  |str12|1  |str16|0  |str19|
|2  |str13|1  |str14|0  |str17|
|2  |str13|1  |str14|0  |str18|
+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 1):

The below is an rdd based solution:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.createDataFrame(List(
  (1, "a,b,c,d", "e,f,g,h", "i,j,k"),
  (2, "a2,b2,c2,d2", "e2,f2,g2,h2", "i2,j2,k2")
))
val ans = df.rdd.flatMap(x => {
  for {
    col1 <- x.getString(1).split(",")
    col2 <- x.getString(2).split(",")
    col3 <- x.getString(3).split(",")
  } yield (x.getInt(0), col1, col2, col3)
})
ans.toDF().show(100, false)
```